# Thread not stopping

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have a thread and in that thread I declared a boolean like so:

```
volatile boolean stopThread = false;
```

Then in my thread look something like this:

```
public void run() {

    while (!stopThread) {

        while (i < list.size()) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }

    }

}
```

The threads are started like so:

```
t1 = new CheckThread();
t2 = new CheckThread();
```

Every thing works fine but I'd like to allow the user to stop the thread so I created a button and added the following two lines:

```
t1.stopThread = true;
t2.stopThread = true;
```

But when I click the button the thread still runs. I also tried the following

```
CheckThread.stopThread = true;
```

But that doesn't work either. **Why are my threads not stopping?**

EDIT:

I start my thread like so. I have a class and outside any methods I have these two variables

```
CheckThread t1;
CheckThread t2;
```

When the button is clicked I then do the following

```
t1 = new CheckThread();
t2 = new CheckThread();

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

I know the thread is running because I have a print statement in the thread.

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Start by removing the _static_ keyword from the stopThread declaration.  That should be an instance variable.

Comment: I've removed the *static* keyword, thread is still not stopping.

Comment: why not use the .interrupt method of Thread and have a check for .isinterrupted() or whatever in your threads execution loop?

Comment: Obviously something else is happening. Post how you start and stop your thread. Post the actual while loop too.

Comment: You say the threads are _started_ by creating a new `CheckThread` object, but that doesn't implicitly start a thread; you'd need to invoke `.start()`. Are you doing that from the constructor, or some place else?

Comment: How do you know your thread is not stopping, what is it doing?

Comment: Are you sure the button is associated with the listener which invokes stopThread = true

Comment: I've added more information, and yes I'm sure the button is being clicked.

Comment: Does whatever is abbreviated by `//Do something` terminate?

Comment: With the information you've provided, we can't reproduce this.

Comment: Post your actual while loop and your button listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What has to be done is add another condidtion in the second while loop so it would look like so

```
while (i < list.size() && !stopThread) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

This would exit out of the second while stopping the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the value of `i` ever changing so I assume what is going is that your inner loop is infinite. I'm not sure what your intention is with the list but the point is that it appears that once the inner loop is entered, the value of `stopThread` doesn't matter.

Maybe this (change value of i):

```
while (!stopThread) {

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Or like this (no inner loop):

```
while (!stopThread) {

    if (i < list.size()) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Or this (no inner loop):

```
while (!stopThread && i < list.size()) {

    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```